# Convert an ajax request into an object?

Tags: jquery

I am making several jquery xml requests and some need to be called on document ready and others need called by a function call? I am noticing a lot of code duplicates because I am wrapping the xml requests in a function. so here is an example.

```
      $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "english.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: 
  function searchStr(xml, val){
  val = val.toLowerCase();
    $(xml).find("a").each(function(){
      $(this).find('b').each(function(){
       $(this).find('c').each(function(){
        $(this).find('d').each(function(){
      //calculations
        });
        $(this).find('d2').each(function(){
                                               //calculations
        });
       });
      });
     });
  }
 });
```

This first one is being called on document ready....

```
    function searchForString(val){
           $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "english.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: 
      function searchStr(xml, val){
      val = val.toLowerCase();
        $(xml).find("a").each(function(){
          $(this).find('b').each(function(){
           $(this).find('c').each(function(){
            $(this).find('d').each(function(){
          //calculations
            });
            $(this).find('d2').each(function(){
                                                   //calculations
            });
           });
          });
         });
      }
     });
}
```

This second on is being called when needed and is passed a parameter of val.
I guess the main question is: how can i convert the ajax call to an object or reusable function so that i can accomplish the above without having to rewrite the ajax request. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define

```
function processXML(xml, val) {
    //do all you need here
}
```

somewhere in the code and make it success handler for both ajax calls

Comment: so, when i do the function call... do i need to pass processXML(null, val); ?

Comment: why null? `success: function(xml) { processXML(xml, val); }`. You can even put the whole `$.ajax(...)` body inside a method, if the calls are identical. This way you'll need to parametrize your method with `val`

Comment: ok... thank you ... i was wrapping the whole ajax call inside the method so i guess it was looking for the xml where the val should be. Thank you, this works

Comment: one more question, how can i simplify these nested xml foreach statements? they seem a little bloated.

Comment: not sure. there should be some jQuery or other third-party tools to deal with xml in javascript. maybe even there is something built-in. try to google it or create a separate question here.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the function globally accessible perhaps ?